# Prolog find elements in the list with accumulator

Tags: prolog

I am trying to understand accumulators, so I want this implementation to contain them.
I have figured how to search through a simple list.
This counts the number of occurrences of a given element:

```
find(Element,[],A,A).
find(Element, [H|Tail], A, N) :- Element = H, A1 is A + 1,
find(Element, Tail, A1, N). 
find(Element, [H|Tail], A, N) :- find(Element, Tail, A, N).
```

Now how can I do I make it work for nested lists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should simply add another item to the matcher such that if `H` is a list as well, the number of occurrences are counted first:

```
find(Element,[],A,A).
find(Element, [Element|Tail], A, N) :-
    !,
    A1 is A + 1,
    find(Element, Tail, A1, N).
find(Element,[[H|T]|Tail],A,N) :-
    !,
    find(Element,[H|T],A,R),
    find(Element,Tail,R,N).
find(Element, [H|Tail], A, N) :-
    find(Element, Tail, A, N).
```

By placing the equality of `Element` (second clause) before the list recursion, you can also search lists in lists. In other words:

```
find([1,2],[[1,2],[3],4,[1,2]])
```

Will return `2`.

You use a cut (`!`) to prevent Prolog from backtracking.

---

> > *Hint:* don't unify in the body (`Element = H`) if possible. Simply reuse the same variable in the head (`find(Element,[Element|Tail],A,N)`). Many Prolog compilers are able to optimize the latter much better than the first case.

---

> > *Hint:* use cuts. You can use cuts more often to prevent Prolog from non-determinism. For instance if you count the occurences of `5` in `[5,1,2,5]` it can come up with `2`, `1` and `0` since you never specify in your last clause that `H` is **not equal** to `Element`. By placing a cut in the previous clause, the Prolog interpreter will never backtrack over this.

Comment: I think there is a mistake in your middle term: find(Element,[H|T],A,T),
    find(Element,Tail,T,N). I get how you split it, but the last and second to last variables shouldn't coincide with T of [H|T]. Am I right?

Comment: Whoops indeed, you should use another variable than `T`. Sorry, but I hope you get the point? Fixed.

Comment: @user3614293: Why should you backtrack over the `find` predicate. They will only prevent in in a `find` call. Since there is no reason to backtrack (the algorithm is "straight forward"), there is no scenario where this is useful.